# mysql descrição

Tags: mysql, query

olhem meu código

```
select count(alunocursos.codAluno), alunocursos.codCurso from
alunocursos join aluno on (aluno.id = alunocursos.codAluno) group by
alunocursos.codCurso
```

isso vai fazer me retornar a quantidade de alunos que realizou cada curso
eu tenho também a tabela cursos (id, descricao)

como eu faço para na query acima me retornar, em vez de id do curso, a descrição do curso?

Comment: Coloque o MER, se possivel, fica mais fácil para ajudar.

Comment: Olha só o que você programou aqui: `GROUP BY alunocurso.codCurso` ... deveria pedir para agrupar pela **DESCRIÇÃO** do curso. Já tentou?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumindo que a tabela `alunocursos` tem vinculo com a tabela `cursos` você conseguiria fazer isso utilizando dois `INNER JOINS`:

```
SELECT COUNT(alunocursos.codAluno), alunocursos.codCurso, cursos.descricao FROM
alunocursos 
INNER JOIN aluno ON (aluno.id = alunocursos.codAluno),
INNER JOIN cursos ON (cursos.id = alunocursos.codCurso)    
GROUP BY alunocursos.codCurso;
```

Deste modo retorna tanto o `codCurso` como a descrição dele, se você quiser que retorne apenas a descrição basta retirar o `alunocursos.codCurso` do `SELECT`.